# Alignment of image (via includegraphics) in fancyhdr with and without tabular environment

Tags: fancyhdr, letters, letterhead

Below I show two examples; an image (via includegraphics) is placed in fancyhdr with and without tabular environment.  When the image is placed in the tabular environment, a vertical offset is apparent, the cause of which is unknown to me.  Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Common files:

address.tex

```
868 Sunrise Ave. \\
Garden City \\
```

body.tex

```
\lipsum[1]
```

First example, no tabular environment:

theletter.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{theletter}[]
\LoadClass[]{letter}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{catchfile}

\RequirePackage[showframe,%
textwidth=345.0pt,%
top=2in,
headheight=1.0in,
headsep=0.20in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\getaddressfrom}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}

\signature{Mae L. Mann}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead[L]{%
\includegraphics[height=1.0in, keepaspectratio=true]{image.png}%
}%
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
\makeatother
  \begingroup\def\tempa{\endgroup\begin{letter}{1234 Central St. \\ Western City}}
    \expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\thefromaddress}%
  \opening{\theopening}
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\closing{\theclosing}
\ps{\thepostscript}
\end{letter}
}
```

aletter.tex

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{theletter}
\getaddressfrom{address.tex}
\newcommand{\theopening}{Dear Recipient}
\newcommand{\theclosing}{Sincerely,}
\newcommand{\thepostscript}{}
\begin{document}
\input{body.tex}
\end{document}
```

I am attaching the output associated with this example first, followed by the output from the second example.  The files associated with the second example are as follows:

thelettertabular.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{theletter}[]
\LoadClass[]{letter}

\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{catchfile}

\RequirePackage[showframe,%
textwidth=345.0pt,%
top=2in,
headheight=1.0in,
headsep=0.20in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\getaddressfrom}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}

\signature{Mae L. Mann}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead[L]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[height=1.0in, keepaspectratio=true]{image.png}%
\end{tabular}
}%
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
\makeatother
  \begingroup\def\tempa{\endgroup\begin{letter}{1234 Central St. \\ Western City}}
    \expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\thefromaddress}%
  \opening{\theopening}
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\closing{\theclosing}
\ps{\thepostscript}
\end{letter}
}
```

And finally the call of the second example: bletter.tex

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{thelettertabular}
\getaddressfrom{address.tex}
\newcommand{\theopening}{Dear Recipient}
\newcommand{\theclosing}{Sincerely,}
\newcommand{\thepostscript}{}
\begin{document}
\input{body.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from first example][image: Output from second example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All TeX boxes are aligned such that their reference point is on the baseline of the horizontal box being built.

The reference point of the box constructed by `\includegraphics` is its bottom left corner and your first image shows the bottom of the image on the baseline.

The reference point of a `tabular` is its vertical center and your second image shows the baseline going through the centre of the image.

If you use `\begin{tabular}[t]` (or `[b]`) the reference point of the tabular would be the baseline of the first (or last) row, which is the baseline of the image, as there is only one row.

Comment: Thank you; far too much effort on my part for such a silly oversight.